# Python 3: How do I place an incrementing literal in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, variables

I want to set up a list of buttons inside a loop, with each button's command calling a function with a different value.

```
for rank in range(21):
    self._rankButton.append(Button(self, text = "Rank " + str(rank),
        command = self._setDice(rank))

self._rankButton[0] should call self._setDice(0)
self._rankButton[1] should call self._setDice(1)
.
.
.
self._rankButton[20] should call self._setDice(20)
```

the only way I get this to work is by configuring the buttons individually outside the loop

Comment: You can use a dictionary to store functions , and call them in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what the `Button` is, but it looks like it expects a function to be called. So you must create that function:

```
...., command=lambda r=rank: self._setDice(r)
```

This should work, unfortunately it is not well readable. First `lambda` means `makefunction`. Second, there is a issue with late binding, that's why we must introduce `r`, because `rank` will have another value at the time this will be called.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that.  The buttons were all calling the function and submitting the last value of rank (20).

Comment: @rgblaine Well, you're welcome, but you should not have accepted the answer before trying it.